# Can `scanf("%*s")` fail?

Tags: c

I want to write a C program counting the words of a text file. I use the loop below:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%*s") != EOF ) {
    count++;
}
```

`fp` points to a text file. Is it possible that this `fscanf()` function have an early matching failure? Because I think it will definitely reach the end of the file, so the `!= EOF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program should work as expected as `fscanf(fp, "%*s")` returns `0` except for input failures where it returns `EOF`. Unless you make the input stream wide oriented and there is an encoding error, input failures should only occur for end of file and read errors.

`fscanf(fp, "%*s")` never returns `1` because the `*` causes the input match to be ignored in the return value, only the **assigned** converted values are counted:

> **7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function**
>
> ...
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `fscanf` function returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

This can be verified with this program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int res = scanf("%*s");
    printf("scanf(\"%%*s\") -> %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

```
chqrlie$ ./scanf0 < /dev/null
scanf("%*s") -> -1
chqrlie$ echo 'test' | ./scanf0
scanf("%*s") -> 0
```

For your purpose, you might write this alternative which emphasizes the expected return value:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%*s") == 0) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: I like your  `==` compare.  `!=` involves negations which is an extra step of mental resolution.  Don't you not disagree? ;-)

Comment: It's actually satisfying to see your `== 0` approach compared to my novice `!= EOF`.

Comment: Comparing the return value of `fscanf()` with the expected value is much safer, especially when at least one conversion gets stored. This specific example is a corner case as only 2 values are possible, but in general more are possible.

Comment: Note also how unfriendly this function is: even very savvy programmers get some of the behavior wrong. I had to investigate it thoroughly to implement it in my own C library and the devil is in the detail.

Comment: @chqrlie Clicked.